# list blobs of different directory in Azure blob Storage

Tags: azure, blob, azure-blob-storage, azure-data-lake-gen2, blobstorage

We have below folder structure in which we have stored data in Azure data lake.

[image]

I want to list all the blobs which are present in the Data directory.
ie. abc.txt,xyz.txt,lmn.txt,abc1.txt,xyz1.txt,lmn1.txt,abc2.txt,xyz2.txt,lmn2.txt,gh.txt,kim.txt,tae.txt,....

How can I get all the blobs which are in Data Directory only?

Folder structure image in Azure:
[image]

I want to get all the blobs that are present in the data folder of all the users, from every year and month folder.

code:

```
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace DataLake
{
   class Program
    { 
      static void Main(string[] args)
      {
          CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("connection string");
        CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
        CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("dev");


        List<string> blobnames = new List<string>();

        var allblobs = container.ListBlobs(useFlatBlobListing: true);
        foreach (var b in allblobs)
        {
            //Console.WriteLine("\t" + b.Uri);
            string name = ((CloudBlockBlob)b).Name;
      //      Console.WriteLine(name);
            string[] names = name.Split('/');
            blobnames.Add(names[names.Length - 1]);

        }
        foreach (var data in blobnames)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(data);
        }


    }
}
```

}

output:
[image]

Comment: Can you please specify which programming language you are using?

Comment: I am using c# to implement this

Answer (score 0):

Try with using `useFlatBlobListing`

I tested  in my system  try with this code

```
  using Microsoft.Azure.Storage;
using Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob;
using System;

using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;

namespace BlobList
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {




            CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("Connection String");
            CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
            CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("test");


            List<string> blobnames = new List<string>();
            //var allblobs = container.ListBlobs(prefix: "test1/test2", useFlatBlobListing: true);
            var allblobs = container.ListBlobs(useFlatBlobListing: true);
            foreach (var b in allblobs)
            {
                //Console.WriteLine("\t" + b.Uri);
                string name = ((CloudBlockBlob)b).Name;
                Console.WriteLine(name);
                string[] names = name.Split('/');
                blobnames.Add(names[names.Length - 1]);




            }
            foreach (var data in blobnames)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(data);
            }


        }


    }
}
```

I tried with creating same folder structure that you have

[image]

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: I used as you suggested but I am not getting the response as expected. I have edited the question you can check there.

Comment: Hi vaishali, you commented  the split operation .Please remove that comments and and can you please copy same code as  I mentioned in answer .try again and let me know still you facing issue.

Comment: I removed the comments I am getting the same response. Edited that in question as well.

Comment: and comment the   '`Console.WriteLine(name);` this  line

Comment: It gives all the folder name and blobs present in other folders as well

Comment: Can you just share the output image along with folder structure in Storage account ,Again  I tried with modifying the folder structure I tested in my system getting proper output

Comment: I added a folder structure image that image show blobs for one user

Comment: I tried with creating same folder structure as you have able to get proper answer .Updated the answer please check it

Comment: I am still getting the same response. In your code, you have done "string[] names = name.Split("/");"  I am getting error on that line so I did this change "string[] names = name.Split(Convert.ToChar("/"));"

Comment: what error you are getting on this line `string[] names = name.Split("/")`

Comment: cannot convert from 'string' to 'char'

Comment: `string[] names = name.Split('/');`, Just try with this line. Instead of double quotes  single quotes

Comment: I have uploaded my entire code with output

Comment: Y you using `WindowsAzure.Storage` legacy Storage SDK , I used the `Microsoft.Azure.Storage` SDK

Comment: Try with using the `Microsoft.Azure.Storage` SDK

Comment: I installed this using Nuget package but as you can see I am not able to use that I am getting error

Comment: I updated the full  code . Search package in Nuget Manager and install it .Please refer this image : https://i.stack.imgur.com/95du8.png

Comment: I made all the changes but still getting the same response

Comment: I found that Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob is also deprecated and methods CloudStorageAccount is available in that. Replacement of is Azure.Storage.Blobs

Comment: Have you tried it again ? Still facing the issue?

Comment: If the answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you